Running a drain for a bathroom sink and toilet into shared drain
Seattle, WA - I've got an odd layout where I have a bathroom in the basement and a water closet directly above it on the main floor. When building the bathroom, we put a 3" vertical pipe in the wall as a provision for the water closet we'd add later.
My goal is to branch off that capped 3" running in the wall and add a toilet and sink drain above the bathroom for the water closet.
How can I improve this plan?
I've highlighted the new header joists I'm adding in order to get the toilet drain to fit dead center in the room above. The yellow lines are both pitched at 2 degrees. The end of the 3x2" combo will be a cleanout cap. I know it's excessive to run 2" for a bathroom sink, but I'm just using the fittings I already own and will reduce it down to 1.5" where it mates to the P trap.
I'll have a studor vent on the sink. I realize that's likely not venting the toilet correctly. Wide open to ideas.




What plumbing code applies to your location on the planet?

If your LAHJ does not have a provision striking out language from the national model codes most local codes are based on, a mechanical vent {aka Studor®, Air Admittance Valve (AAV) - many names for the same thing}  if properly sized and properly installed/located is code accepted. And the layout has the toilet downstream of the Lavatory, which is the proper setup for wet-venting a bathroom group as defined in model codes.
We don't know what your applicable code is, as you have not specified that.
Best practice for installing a mechanical vent is to extend the vent pipe as high as possible (thus, in new construction, running it up inside the wall cavity above counter level is preferred, rather than the commonly-seen under-counter install.) It needs to be accessible (so put an access door in the wall) and threaded on for easy replacement when it fails and needs to be replaced. If installing it under the counter it should be as high up under the counter as possible while still being able to be unthreaded and replaced. The further it is from the trap water level, the longer it's going to last, to a large extent.
Unclear why "planning for future water closet" did not include "Planning a connection to the vent stack for it" (and I personally greatly prefer a connection to the vent stack to a mechanical vent) but whether or not you can just use a mechanical vent is dependent on your local adopted applicable code.

Thanks for your time! It’s a tricky spot. Accessing the vent stack would mean seriously compromising the structure of the joists between the area shown above and the main stack. We already have multiple circuits and 12 lines of PEX running through the joists on 4” centers for hydronic heat upstairs. I’ll be sure to run the studor vent as high as possible. Also, I added my location to the original post. Rookie move.
